# how to insert multiple row's data of a table with single query in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table which has multiple rows and the number of rows is not fixed. To be more exact, sometimes it might have 3 rows and sometimes it might have 30 rows depending on users demand. I want to store all row's data of that table into mysqli Database in single query. If it is not possible with a single query, i wish to know if there is any other solution for it. my codes are as belows:

**HTML**

```
   <form role="form" method="post">
          <table class="table" id="dataTable">
            <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD><input type="hidden" value="1" name="num" id="orderdata">1</TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="medname" class="form-control" id="orderdata" placeholder="Your Medicine name"/></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="medqty" class="form-control" id="orderdata" placeholder="Quantity" /></TD>
            <TD>
               <SELECT name="medtype" class="form-control" id="orderdata">
                  <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                  <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
              </TD>
          </TR>
  </table>
         <div class="center-block">
                    <span> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">Add More</button></span>
                    <span> <button type="button" value="Delete Row" class="btn btn-success" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">Delete</button></span>
                    <span><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button></span>
                    <br>

                </div>  

            </form>
```

**PHP**

```
  <?php

    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    $cell = "Select `cellno` FROM `userreg` WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $cell);
    $cellno = "";
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $cellno = $row["cellno"];
        }
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $fullname = $_SESSION["fullname"];
        $medname = $_POST['medname'];
        $medqty  = $_POST['medqty'];
        $medtype = $_POST['medtype'];
        $num = $_POST['num'];
        $date = date("Y.m.d");


      $medorder = "INSERT INTO `medorder` (`fullname`, `phoneno`, `medname`, `quantity`, `medtype`, `date`,`orderno` ) VALUES ('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' )";

      if($conn->query($medorder)=== TRUE) {
        echo"<br>";
        echo " Your Question has been submitted successfully";
      }

      else {
        echo " Error!! Try again or later";
      }

   }     


?>
```

Comment: INSERT INTO `medorder` (`fullname`, `phoneno`, `medname`, `quantity`, `medtype`, `date`,`orderno` ) VALUES ('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' ),('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' ),('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' ),('$fullname', '$cellno', '$medname','$medqty', '$medtype', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$num' ) is it something you are looking at?

Comment: Yes, you can insert multiple sets of values together. "INSERT INTO table (field names..) VALUES (set1), (set2), (set3)" etc... But keep in mind that SQL servers have query length limitations, which means that you cannot send too long queries to the server. Your query cannot exceed the limit. You can check your server limit by:  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Comment: no... i am not looking for this.. my table rows are dynamic. sometimes users can pick 4 rows and sometimes can pick 13 rows. and after completing the tables form data..when users press the submit button all table's data should be stored in the DB. no matter how much numbers of row are there.